# How to get ASTContext from an Expr in Clang LibTooling?

Tags: clang, libtooling

For Decl, there is getASTContext(), but being AST node as Decl, why doesn't Expr have the function like that and how to get ASTContext from an Expr?

Note: Decl is https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html, Expr is https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Expr.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to get the ASTContext from an Expr or Type; only from a Decl. However, you could get the ASTContext from an Expr through Type by downcasting to the child type and then getting the Decl from the child type.

For example:

```cpp
clang::QualType QualType = Expr->getType();
const clang::Type* Type = QualType.getTypePtr();
const clang::DecltypeType* Decltype =
    static_cast<const clang::DecltypeType*>(Type);
const clang::Decl* Decl = Decltype->getAs<clang::Decl>();
const clang::ASTContext& Context = Decl->getASTContext();
```

Of course, this does not always work because not all Types are Decl-Types.